# Get all cities in latitude/longitude range

Tags: math, gps

I have a list of cities, each of them obviously has a longitude and latitude.

Now selecting one of these cities, i want to obtain all the other cities that have a longitude / latitude in  a range of 50 km from the selected city.
What formula should I use?

**I am only interested in the mathematical formula to convert km to  latidutine and longitude from a know city position**

Then i will calculate the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude, for considering an acceptable  range. (like a Square)

tks

---

I don't want to calculate the distance between two points!+
I want to calculate min e max latitude and longitude and then filter my cities by this coordinates.

I've found a sample in Php that worked for me. 
(i've ported it to C#)

http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/08/geo-proximity-search-the-haversine-equation/

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want to use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

You may want to check out the following articles for further reading and for a few implementations in various languages:

- [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) by Chris Veness.
- [Calculate Distance Between Two Points on a Globe in 11 languages](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Great Circle calculation.  It returns the shortest distance across the surface of the planet given two points and their respective latitude and longitude.  There is a great Wikipedia article here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

There is a pretty decent implementation - source code in javascript here:
http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/GreatCircleAlgorithms